# Mac M1 - OS: Big Sur 11.6 - Не работает копирование из крона

Tags: bash, mac, crontab

Всем добра.

Скрипт по сути простейший, его по сути нет 1 команда:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mv ~/Downloads/*.torrent ~/APS/Watcher
```

Пробовал всяко и так тоже:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mv /Users/pebody/Downloads/*.torrent /Users/pebody/APS/Watcher
```

Из терминала из под своего юзера работает без проблем, крон не хочет делать хоть ты че делай 8-( пробовал засунуть в крон рута, тоже самое, реакций 0 ни mv ни cp ни rm не делает из под крона.

В чем дело? Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Как и в какой крон вы добавили этот скрипт?

Comment: В тьерминале пишем crontab -e это крон текущего пользователя. В кроне стандартные значения, к примеру на скрипт у меня: 

5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * /bin/sh /Users/pebody/tor

Рядом стоит похожий скрипт в той же папки, те же права на исполнение, все 1 в 1 но в скрипте монтирование томов по smb, все работает, а копирование НЕТ.

Спасибо.

Comment: Также я прописал уникальные пути для рута и добавлял в крон рута с полными путями до скрипта, в самом скрипте переделал все пути на уникальные с корня до объектов досканально = толку 0... как будто команды cp mv rm запрещены для крона... хз (

Answer (score 1):

Идете в раздел безопасности и добавляете /usr/sbin/cron для полного доступа к диску. Все работает:

Full Disk Access
Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access:

Click on the (+) icon to add an item to the list:
Press command+shift+G then type /usr/sbin/cron and Enter, you can find cron